# How to handle/get access to "deep" Errors in MathNet: what is parameter 4?

Tags: mathnet-numerics

I execute

```
d = (DenseMatrix)k.Solve(F);
```

And get an InvalidParameterException:

```
Message = "An invalid parameter was passed to a native method, parameter number : 4"
```

What is parameter nr. 4? Where did I pass it into MathNet?
How can I find out what is going wrong and what I can do about it?
I suspect some LaPack-ish routine is called internally with wrong parameters.
Are these errors accessible in any way?

Hm... I found here: https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Providers.LinearAlgebra/ILinearAlgebraProvider%601.htm#LUFactor

that LUFactor(...) might be the LaPack routine dgetrf.

And at the LaPack doc, I found that the fourth argument of dgetrf is LDA (assuming base 1), a matrix dimension size. But then, how does that number get wrong? I don't enter it anywhere and comes directly from the (c#, MathNet) DenseMatrix itself.

Comment: Can you show more code? What are `k` and `F`?